# Using Hyphen/Dash in db_query regex

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

The query

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP "foo-bar";
```

Returns results as expected, however when executing what I believe to be the functional equivalent in Drupal

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP (:regex)", array("regex"=>"\"foo-bar\""));
```

does not return any results.. I'm wondering if it may be caused by the hyphen being used to with regex ranges etc but cannot find any relevant workarounds.

Edit: Although I have tried similar to Robins post earlier, following on that train of thought, the following returns results:

```
$bar = db_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%foo-bar%' ")
```

Yet,

```
$bar = db_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE ':regex' ", array("regex"=>"%foo-bar%"));
```

or any variations (such as moving percents from the arg to the query) do not.

I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong or if there is an issue with string replacement getting escaped by drupal, but [Drupal db_query documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) doesn't mention regex in the argument and I don't believe hypens are escaped for security/display purposes..

ps. be gentle, first Stackover flow post, and new to Drupal and MySQL ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a syntax issue. It looks like db_query encapsulates strings with quotations.

The following statements behave as expected:

```
$bar = db_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP (:regex) ", array("regex"=>"foo-bar"));
```

and

```
$bar = db_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE (:regex) ", array("regex"=>"%foo-bar%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%foo-bar%'
```

It will work for you.

Comment: This is a Drupal question, the statement already works in MySQL, but revised initial question to be a little clearer.